# Exception while starting my application in websphere 8.5.5.14

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-8

I installed websphere 8.5.5.14 and started the server and verify WAS working with a sample application installation and running and looks good.

After i installed my working application successfuly. Then i start the application, i could the following exception. Any thoughts / suggestions would be helpful to resolve this issue in my local?

Exception details...
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.Binder

FFDC Exception:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError SourceId:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup ProbeId:131 Reporter:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl@99aa9a78
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.Binder

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.Binder

FFDC Exception:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException SourceId:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer ProbeId:736 Reporter:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer@44447274
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.Binder

Comment: You're apparently missing library which contains class `org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.Binder`

Comment: Thanks for your thought.. after i added this jar in the shared lib https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-api (v2.1.58), i could see the other glassfish class jar error.. Do we have any list of dependencies of this glassfish jars, so that i can refer and download all and attach.

Comment: I added the glassfish jar references to my appln. \n Stop and Start WebSphere Server \n Then after starting, i could see this exception \n FFDC Exception:com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning SourceId:com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl ProbeId:297 Reporter:com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl@2421cda5
com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocatorFactory$CreatePolicy

Comment: FYI - after adding the following jars, my errors resolved. org.glassfish.hk2-utils
org.glassfish.hk2-locator
org.glassfish.hk2-api